# Create new Azure Website from an exiting backup Azure website

Tags: azure

I have a running Azure website using Umbraco template. As per business requirement I need to host the same website to a newly created Azure Website.

For that I have backup the running Website using "**cloudcellar"**. But not finding any options to deploy the backup to my newly created web site(Re-store options is available in cloudcellar but that restore in the old Website only).

I will continue to research but if any of you know the answer (how can I easily restore Azure website to newly created website ) please feel free to weigh in!

Answer (score 0):

There is more info on it at Cloud Cellars site [Restore from Backup](http://ruslany.net/2013/06/cloud-cellar-azure-web-sites-backup-service/)

Basically there is a giant green 'Restore' button on the bottom of the Cloud Cellar Dashboard that you click. :)